# Russell Paradox and set theories

Tags: set-theory, philosophy, paradoxes

The Russell paradox arise in the Cantor set theory, but it can be avoided in the $ZF$ and in $NGB$ axiomatic set theory. Are there other axiomatic set theories in which this paradox can be avoided? Thanks.

Comment: Aaargh. The Russel paradox does not arise in the set theory of Cantor. It was a paradox for the set theory of Frege. And no theory that we would call a set theory today allows for the paradox.

Comment: Much like when defining a function you first check whether or not it is well defined, there is a list of usual paradoxes which one checks when defining axioms of set theory. Russell's one is probably the first.

Comment: Quine's [New Foundations](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/New_Foundations) avoids the paradox by forbidding comprehension over the poisonous predicates.

Comment: Possibly also useful: [Elementary Set Theory With a Universal Set](http://math.boisestate.edu/~holmes/holmes/head.pdf).

Comment: Every set theory built on standard logic tries to avoid the known difficulties. Whether it succeeds is another matter. The only exceptions are set theories based on paraconsistent logics, which limit the damage done by $A\land \lnot A$ in other ways.

Comment: Most (if not all) modern set theories avoid Russell's paradox by limiting set construction principles.  In particular, the [_Comprehension Scheme_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) is restricted so that a definable class is a set only if it is a subclass of a set.

Comment: @Arthur I prefer NBG set theory models over ZF models because I want to be able to give a common foundation to both category theory and set theory and NBG does that. (So does Quine's NF,but NF has major issues that make it very problematic as a foundation for mathematics.) But in the case of any set theory that allows proper classes, the CS restriction is even MORE important since the set of all sets-if it exists-is a proper class.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234: I'm not certain if the CS restriction is _more_ important in either NBG or MK set theory than in ZFC.  In either case, it serves the same purpose.  A ZFC-like theory with an unrestricted CS would give a _set_ of all sets, since there is nothing else for this definable object to be.  NBG has the the Axiom of Limitation of Size which itself implies that $V$ is a proper class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is mentioned in comments above, the so called *Russell paradox* is a consequence of non-restricted Comprehension Schema according to which for any formula $\varphi(x)$, where $x$ is free, $\{x\mid\varphi(x)\}$ is a set. This paradox is actually a result of a logical truth ($R$ is a binary predicate):
$$
\neg\exists x\forall y(yRx\iff \neg yRy)\,.
$$
In light of this, assuming non-restricted comprehension in a language in which you have at least one binary predicate you always get inconsistent theory. Thus if you want to build a set theory based on classical logic you must restrict the schema one way or another.

EDIT: This address Asaf question below (I should have written it before it was asked). As I wrote above, if you build a system of set theory you must restrict the Comprehension Schema. All such restrictions I am aware of allow you to avoid falling into inconsistency due to Russell paradox.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this is an answer to this question really...

Comment: @Asaf: I edited my answer a bit. Hope you can read my intentions now.